# Collaborative text editor for Mac and Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, syntax-highlighting, collaboration

I am looking for a collaborative text editor for mac and windows with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) a few times in the past. It supports Windows, Linux and a Mac port seems available, too. It supports syntax highlighting.